# Calculating the modulo of large numbers in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

For an IBAN Validation, I need to calculate the modulo of a very large number. What I am doing is simply

Example:

with `A1 = 210501700012345678131468`

`=mod(A1;97)`

The result should be `1`. Instead it result in `#NUM`

Obviously my value in `A1` is too large for sheets. How can I "help" sheets?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I suggest that you research more widely to build your IBAN validation since modulo alone is not going to cut it. According to [Google Sheets not processing very large numbers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123028/196152) (webapps by the ubiquitous @Rubén) fifteen digits are recognized as number but sixteen digits are recognised as text. There's an Apps script IBAN validator on [gsuitefr.blogspot.com](https://gsuitefr.blogspot.com/2020/01/verifier-la-validite-dun-numero-iban-en.html) worth looking at - its modulo takes the IBAN as a string and processes it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your number-strings are 24 digits/characters in length, you should be able to use this:

`=MOD( (MOD(LEFT(A2,12),97) * MOD(10^12,97)) + MOD(RIGHT(A2,12),97) ,97)`

If your divisor will change, you can substitute each instance of `97` with a cell reference and then simply change the cell reference.